# С++ вывод изображения на весь экран поверх всех окон

Tags: c++

Хочу написать программу, при выполнении которой затемнялся бы экран и выводилось окно с кнопкой. Как к примеру запуск программы от имени администратора. Но я не знаю с чего начать и что изучать, а в интернете ничего вразумительного по этому поводу не нашел. Помогите с направлением.))

Comment: Тут нужно не с++ изучать, а взаимодействие с Windows. А уж на каком языке оно будет произведено - VB, C++, C# - дело вторичное. Конкретно то, что требуется, можно сделать как скринсейвер, путем рисования в полноэкранном режиме с предварительным сохранением буфера экрана.

Comment: @DreamChild
Нет,искал по запросам тип: c++ вывод изображения поверх окон.....)

Comment: @gecube для меня ответ вообще ни о чем не говорит, я нуб в этом, к сожалению, киньте ссылки или ключевые слова для поиска.

Comment: @LaKO, ну, примеры работы с DirectX могли бы и сами найти. [Например][1]. По поводу скринсейверов - ну, две ссылки из гугля выцепить можно сразу: [раз][2] и [два][3]. Просто нужно немного поинтересоваться =)

[1]:http://www.directxtutorial.com/Lesson.aspx?lessonid=11-4-4
[2]:http://habrahabr.ru/post/141011/
[3]:http://kaimi.ru/2011/11/simple-screensaver/

Comment: @DreamChild: Гугл по вашей ссылке привёл меня снова сюда. Рекурсия!